# Integrating a non-separable differential equation

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I need to integrate

$$
dx = [k-\lambda x] dt / \tau
$$

to solve for x(t), where k, $\lambda$, and $\tau$ are constants. However, the equation seems to be non-separable, so I'm not sure how to go about integrating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is separable:
$$\frac{1}{k-\lambda x} dx = \frac{1}{\tau}dt$$

Comment: wow, no idea how I missed that. thanks